# accumulated sales forecast in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, forecast

I have created a sales forecast in Power BI via the built in forecast function. And this works great. However I would also like to have an accumulated sales forecast, to see the total forecast for the next year. Power BI dosent recognize that this is accumulate, as an example, it therefore overestimates Jan 2024 in the accumulated model compared to the regular sales model. Anybody who also have this issue, and figured out a solution, that dosent involve exporting the data from PBI first?

PBI dosent have many built in options for this problem.

In the below figures, green is actual sales and black is predicted sales.

[Regular Forecast model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYT2G.png)

[Accumulated/running total forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmGiJ.png)

Comment: Which "built in forecast function"?

Comment: Power Bi has a built in forecast function when using the line chart. I believe this an exponential smoothing model.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Could you update the question with a snip to highlight the issue?

Comment: It is my first time in here. What is a snip?

Comment: Screen shot of the chart. And how are you doing accumulated calculation?

Comment: Roger, should be done now